# How to modify global variable via function based on Optionmenu selection

Tags: python, tkinter, configuration, optionmenu

I am pretty new to python and am trying to create a product configurator using tkinter optionmenu.  I need to use multiple optionmenus and each value selected should create the next set of data for the next optionmenu.  I have researched everything I can think to get it right, to no avail.

NOTE: the second optionmenu is in a note, as it is not working with the current configuration.  Also, will need 4 optionmenus in total, all based on values selected before them.

Edited code:

```
from tkinter import *


def openForm():
    print('Open Form')
    return


def openParts():
    print('Open Parts')
    return


capChoice = ['No Lift Selected']


def capFilter(liftSelection):
    global capChoice
    if liftSelection == 'Arm':
        capChoice = ['50kg', '100kg', '200kg', '300kg']
    elif liftSelection == 'Arm (Food Grade)':
        capChoice = ['75kg']
    elif liftSelection == 'Rail':
        capChoice = ['125kg', '300kg']
    elif liftSelection == 'Drive':
        capChoice = ['125kg', '300kg']
    print(capChoice)


lengthChoice = ['No Capacity Selected']


def lengthFilter(lengthSelection):
    global lengthChoice
    if lengthSelection == '50kg' and capChoice == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m']
    elif lengthSelection == '75kg':
        lengthChoice = ['4.2m']
    elif lengthSelection == '100kg' and capChoice == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif lengthSelection == '125kg':
        lengthChoice = ['N/A']
    elif lengthSelection == '200kg' and capChoice == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif lengthSelection == '300kg' and capChoice == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m', '4m']
    elif lengthSelection == '300kg' and capChoice == 'Rail':
        lengthChoice = ['N/A']
    elif lengthSelection == '300kg' and capFilter() == 'Drive':
        lengthChoice = ['N/A']


app = Tk()
app.title('QL Form')
app.geometry('560x460+200+200')

menubar = Menu(app)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label='Form', command=openForm)
filemenu.add_command(label='Req Parts', command=openParts)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label='Quit', command=app.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Page', menu=filemenu)

app.config(menu=menubar)

liftType = StringVar()
liftType.set('Lift Type')
files = ['Arm', 'Arm (Food Grade)', 'Rail', 'Drive']
liftDropDown = OptionMenu(app, liftType, *files, command=capFilter)
liftDropDown.pack()

liftCap = StringVar()
liftCap.set('Capacity')
capDropDown = OptionMenu(app, liftCap, *capChoice, command=lengthFilter)
capDropDown.pack()

liftLength = StringVar()
liftLength.set('Length')
capDropDown = OptionMenu(app, liftLength, *lengthChoice, command=lengthFilter)
capDropDown.pack()


app.mainloop()
```

Code before:

```
from tkinter import *


def openForm():
    print('Open Form')
    return


def openParts():
    print('Open Parts')
    return


def capFilter(selection):
    global capChoice
    if selection == 'Arm':
        capChoice = ['50kg', '100kg', '200kg', '300kg']
    elif selection == 'Arm (Food Grade)':
        capChoice = ['75kg']
    elif selection == 'Rail':
        capChoice = ['125kg', '300kg']
    elif selection == 'Drive':
        capChoice = ['125kg', '300kg']
    print(capChoice)
    return capChoice



def lengthFilter(selection):
    if selection == '50kg' and capFilter() == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m']
    elif selection == '75kg':
        lengthChoice = ['4.2m']
    elif selection == '100kg' and capFilter() == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif selection == '125kg':
        lengthChoice = ['N/A']
    elif selection == '200kg' and capFilter() == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif selection == '300kg' and capFilter() == 'Arm':
        lengthChoice = ['3m', '4m']
    elif selection == '300kg' and capFilter() == 'Rail':
        lengthChoice = ['N/A']
    elif selection == '300kg' and capFilter() == 'Drive':
        lengthChoice = ['N/A']
    return lengthChoice


app = Tk()
app.title('QL Form')
app.geometry('560x460+200+200')

menubar = Menu(app)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label='Form', command=openForm)
filemenu.add_command(label='Req Parts', command=openParts)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label='Quit', command=app.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Page', menu=filemenu)

app.config(menu=menubar)

liftType = StringVar()
liftType.set('Lift Type')
files = ['Arm', 'Arm (Food Grade)', 'Rail', 'Drive']
liftDropDown = OptionMenu(app, liftType, *files, command=capFilter)
liftDropDown.pack()


'''
liftCap = StringVar()
liftCap.set('Capacity')
capDropDown = OptionMenu(app, liftCap, *capChoice, command=lengthFilter)
capDropDown.pack()
'''

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Simply _modify_ global values with functions instead of trying to return.

Comment: Even with no return, capChoice and lengthChoice are not updating with the functions.  if I print from inside the function, the value is changed but if I print outside the function, even after it has run, the value is still the original value.

Comment: function used in `command=` , `bind()` or `after()` is executed by `mainloop()` which skips value returned from function. You have to change global variables or you have to update widgets directly.

Comment: where do you print `capChoice` outside function ? you have to remeber that all `print()` before `mainloop()` are executed `before` window` is created so all widgets are empty.

Comment: Code edited to modify global variable but having issue stated in last comment

Comment: you have to create variable `capChoice` before you use it in `OptionMenu` - function `capFilter` create/use this variables much later. But if you event change values in `capChoice` it doesn't change values in `OptionMenu`  because `OptionMenu` only copy values from `capChoice` and later doesn't use this variable.

Comment: in edited code I created the variables first and the Optionmenu should run the function and change its value once I select a value from the Optionmenu, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cap_dropdown` copies values from `cap_choice` at start but later it doesn't use it - so if you even change values in `cap_choice` it will not work.

Inside `cap_filter` you have to replace items directly in `cap_dropdown`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def cap_filter(selection):
    options = {
        'Arm': ['50kg', '100kg', '200kg', '300kg'],
        'Arm (Food Grade)': ['75kg'],
        'Rail': ['125kg', '300kg'],
        'Drive': ['125kg', '300kg'],
    }

    if selection in options:
        items = options[selection]    
    else:
        items = []
    print(items)    

    # remove old elements
    cap_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    # add new items
    for text in items:
        cap_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=text, command=lambda arg=text:length_filter(arg))


def length_filter(selection):
    type_ = lift_type.get()

    if selection == '50kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m']
    elif selection == '75kg':
        length_choice = ['4.2m']
    elif selection == '100kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif selection == '125kg':
        length_choice = ['N/A']
    elif selection == '200kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m', '4m', '5m']
    elif selection == '300kg' and type_ == 'Arm':
        length_choice = ['3m', '4m']
    elif selection == '300kg' and type_ == 'Rail':
        length_choice = ['N/A']
    elif selection == '300kg' and type_ == 'Drive':
        length_choice = ['N/A']
    else:
        length_choice = ['N/A']

    print(length_choice)

app = tk.Tk()

lift_type = tk.StringVar()
lift_type.set('Lift Type')
files = ['Arm', 'Arm (Food Grade)', 'Rail', 'Drive']

lift_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(app, lift_type, *files, command=cap_filter)
lift_dropdown.pack()

lift_cap = tk.StringVar()
lift_cap.set('Capacity')
cap_choice = ['']

cap_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(app, lift_cap, *cap_choice, command=length_filter)
cap_dropdown.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: One more question: wondering why the capacity does not show in the drop box